# Picasa 3.5 faces - mass assignment of people names to photos with undetected faces

Tags: photos, picasa

For photos in Picasa 3.5 that Picasa does not detect any faces in, is it possible to mass assign People names to blocks of photos?  You can do it on a per-photo basis but this is an untenable answer for large numbers of photos.  If Picasa 3.5 detects a face but can't figure it out, it's super-easy to mass assign the People names.  But if it doesn't detect a face at all, I can't figure out how to do en masse.

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest asking this in the Picasa 3.5 for Windows Google forum http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Picasa/label?lid=523d5991dbedd0cd&hl=en.

Comment: It might be worth answering your own question (laying out the exact solution), and then accepting that... I'm still a little confused as to how you're doing it (but would be interested to find out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think jwaddell is right on that one - if you tag the whole photo, it might mess with the tagging algorithm's "training". At least, that's what I'm thinking.

I don't know of any way to mass tag like that anyway - my best idea is to tag a few photos of such undetected faces (open a photo and click the People button and click the Add a person manually button) and see if Picasa catches on and starts giving you other positive identifications of the face (go to their name and click the only show suggestions button to see what Picasa thinks is also them).

Comment: I just finished my comment to jwaddell and then read your part:

"pen a photo and click the People button and click the Add a person manually button) and see if Picasa catches on and starts giving you other positive identifications of the face (go to their name..."

I went to do this, and saw that Picasa *directly* let me manually assign names to photos with undetected faces.  This is exactly what I wanted to accomplish!  

I don't know whether I completely missed this functionality the first time around or whether it came out in a recent releae, but I'm happy!

Answer (score 2):

If Picasa can't detect any faces in a photo, I can't see how it would be possible to do anything other than manually tell Picasa where the faces are. I think assigning a face tag to an entire photo would probably mess with their face-detection algorithm.

It sounds like you actually need Picasa's face-detection algorithm to be better - Google might be interested in examples of faces that have not been detected.

Comment: << I can't see how it would be possible to do anything other than manually tell Picasa where the faces are. I think assigning a face tag to an entire photo would probably mess with their face-detection algorithm. >>

I don't agree - it would only mess up the algorithm if Picasa let it.  I don't think there's anything technical preventing them (other than the decision to include the feature) from allowing you to indicate to Picasa, "this photo has a face".  If the algorithm doesn't detect one, I should be able to override that, effectively training the algorithm.

Comment: UPDATE: Please see my comment to Nathaniel.